# email php script not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, php

I have a desktop working form + javascript handler + php sendtoemail script but when i go into mobile view and use the same scripts + exactly the same form. It starts the javascript which calls the php file but the mail doesn't go as intended. I think the problem is with passing info from javascript to php.

Javascript:

```
function send_message()
        {
            var a=document.forms["Form"]["name"].value;
            var b=document.forms["Form"]["email"].value;
            var c=document.forms["Form"]["message"].value;
            var d=document.forms["Form"]["surname"].value;

            document.getElementById("contact_message").innerHTML = "Sending your message... Please wait.";

            loadXMLDoc(a, b, c, d);
        }


        //pomocna funkcija za validaciju emaila
        function validateEmail(email) {
            var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
            return re.test(email);
        }

        //funkcija za slanje emaila
        function loadXMLDoc(name, mail, message, surname)
        {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("contact_message").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById("contact_message2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
              }

            // xmlhttp.open("GET","send_enquiry.php",true);
            xmlhttp.open("POST","send_enquiry.php",true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send("name=" + name + "&email=" + mail + "&message=" + message + "&surname=" + surname);


        }
```

Then the PHP:

```
<?php
$title = $_POST['title']
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$headers = "From: $email\r\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n".
    "Reply-To: $email\r\n" .
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n" .
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

$headers2 = 
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n".
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n" .
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();


$poruka = $title." ".$name." ".$surname." \n".$email."\n\n".$message;



//server side provjera da li su sve varijable pune
if (($name !== '') && ($email !== '') && ($message !== ''))
{
//provjera da li je mail poslan
    if(@mail('info@delmata-travel.hr', 'delmata-travel.hr - New enquiry', $poruka, $headers))
        print 'Message successfully sent. We will answer as soon as possible. ';
    else
    {
        print 'Sending unsuccessfull. Please try again.';
        mail('info@delmata-travel.hr', 'delmata-travel.hr - Greška', "Desila se greška kod slanja poruke putem kontakt forme. Greška je uzrokovana jer mail nije poslan iz nekog razloga. \n\nPodaci pošiljatelja su: \n".$name." \n".$email." \n".$message, $headers2);
    }
}    
else
{
    print 'Sending unsuccessfull. Please try again.';
    @mail('info@delmata-travel.hr', 'delmata-travel.hr - Greška', "Desila se greška kod slanja poruke putem kontakt forme. Greška je uzrokovana jer svi uneseni podaci nisu bili ispunjeni. Poruka je prosla javascript validaciju, ali nije prošla server side validaciju. \n\nPodaci ako su ispunjeni su sljedeći: \n".$name." \n".$email." \n".$message, $headers2);
}
```

?>

On mobile i'm getting the last else in the if else part of the PHP. It should be that the info is not fully inputed and should result in sending the info that was inputed.

I'm guessing this is not working on mobile cuz the send parameters from javascript to php is not working properly.
I must mention that this form and validation and send email is fully working on desktop version.

The form is exactly the same. Checked 10 times.

Comment: Add some log and check whether request is reached to server or not while making request from mobile device. If request doesn't reach, try using jquery function $.ajax() for making ajax call. It supports cross browser. So it might also fix the issue if client request is not reaching to server.

Comment: I've tried using inline onclick=send_message() and with jquery .on('click', send_message); both resulted in the same way. Is this what you are thinking about?

Comment: I am not saying to use jquery for event binding. Make ajax request using jquery http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp , http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/